# Read FTP file with international characters

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest, ftpwebresponse

I am downloading a FTP location file using below code. Its working for all of the files except where the file name contains international character.

I have learned in the URI format such this is not allowed but how can download if there is existing file at mentioned location.

For testing I have setup local FTP server under IIS like below.

http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/setup-ftp-server-in-windows-iis/

```
string mat_address = "ftp://localhost/";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(mat_address);

ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userid", "Password");
ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

string[] downloadfile = null;
using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftp.GetResponse())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default, true))
{
    downloadfile = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}

foreach (string d in downloadfile)
{
    if (d.Contains("d"))
    {
        string temp = mat_address + HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(d);
        FtpWebRequest ftp2 = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(temp);

        ftp2.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userid", "Password");

        ftp2.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;

        ftp2.UseBinary = true;

        ftp2.Proxy = null;
        ftp2.KeepAlive = false;
        ftp2.UsePassive = false;

        FtpWebResponse response2 = ftp2.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
        DateTime temp1 = response2.LastModified.Date;
        if (temp1 > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10))
        {
           // Some extra work
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error

> The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

[image: File unavailable error]

Below is my FTP root folder with problematic file name as `diá.png`

[image]

I am using C# for coding and Visual Studio 2013 for development. Whats going wrong can someone help.

**Update to Question:** 
Changes in Encoding to UTF8.
Using the local host everything works fine. But when using the FTP server from international domain like germany and sweden. The name is read like below.

I am getting error for the line below.

```
FtpWebResponse response2 = ftp2.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
```

**Hex Value for File Name:**  Suggested include by Martin. Thanks
`31,30,31,33,36,2D,49,43,4F,4D,20,50,4A,C4,54,54,45,52,59,44,20,70,69,63,74,20,37‌​,38,78,31,31,38,20,61,6E,6E,69,2D,76,65,72,73,61,72,69,75,73,20,5B,77,31,33,32,31‌​,20,78,20,68,39,32,31,5D,20,6D,6D,20,44,49,46,46,55,53,45,2E,50,4E,47,`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most FTP servers should use UTF-8 encoding. So does your local (IIS) server.

So you need to use the [`Encoding.UTF8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.utf8), when parsing the directory listing.

---

Though your real/production server seems to be broken in some way. It looks like it uses Windows-1252 encoding for the directory listing. Yet it claims (and seems to require) UTF-8 encoding for commands. That clearly (and rightfully) confuses FileZilla. But I do not see, why it does not work with the `FtpWebRequest` as it should use the UTF-8 (as the server positively responds to `OPTS utf8 on` command), and you have tried to explicitly use the Windows-1252 encoding, when parsing the listing.

---

Anyway, as you found (in chat) that WinSCP works, you can try to use the [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library). It will also make your code a way simpler:

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions();
sessionOptions.Protocol = Protocol.Ftp;
sessionOptions.HostName = "hostname";
sessionOptions.UserName = "username";
sessionOptions.Password = "password";

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    foreach (RemoteFileInfo fileInfo in session.ListDirectory("/textures").Files)
    {
        if (fileInfo.Name.Contains("d"))
        {
            if (fileInfo.LastWriteTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10))
            {
                string sourcePath =
                    RemotePath.EscapeFileMask("/textures/" + fileInfo.Name);
                session.GetFiles(sourcePath, @"c:\local\path\").Check();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or, even simpler, using [file mask with time constraint](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time):

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions();
sessionOptions.Protocol = Protocol.Ftp;
sessionOptions.HostName = "hostname";
sessionOptions.UserName = "username";
sessionOptions.Password = "password";

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    session.GetFiles("/textures/*d*>=10D", @"c:\local\path\").Check();
}
```

See also WinSCP example [How do I transfer new/modified files only?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_modified_files)

Comment: I have updated my question. As you said the Encoding should be UTF8 this is causing me issue and file name which i am going to read from FTP server is coming wrong. I have added this as an update to original question.

Comment: So maybe the real server uses the Ansi encoding. Try `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`. It's difficult to guess. Show us a hex dump of the response stream.

Comment: Ok I will check. @Martin How will i get the HEX dump. Is it the exception?

Comment: I am able to read and download other files but the only files are with international characters in the the file name as discussed.

Comment: There are over 10000+ files on server. The hex dump is coming very huge. How can i get specific file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89245/discussion-between-pratik-and-martin-prikryl).

Comment: Thank you so much for the patience and help me resolve the problem.

Comment: i have included session.EscapeFileMask in code for first one ..bcz that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, you'll have to transform the encoding of the recieved filename to match the needs of your local file system. Could you post what filename you revieve? I think you get an excaped string containing some illegal characters...